# Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' mistake?

Tags: python, apk

E Python  :     raise ImportError(msg)
E Python  : ImportError:
E Python  :
E Python  : IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
E Python  :
E Python  : Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
E Python  : many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
E Python  : installed.
E Python  :
E Python  : We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
E Python  :
E Python  :  https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html  E Python  :
E Python  : Please note and check the following:
E Python  :
E Python  :   * The Python version is: Python3.9 from ""
E Python  :   * The NumPy version is: "1.22.4"
E Python  :
E Python  : and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
E Python  : Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
E Python  :
E Python  : Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
E Python  :

> Excuse me, am I having a problem here? Where should I go to set it up?
> <<<<<* The Python version is: Python3.9 from "">>>>

**I converted py to apk, but now it will jump out by itself when it works
I have check environment，There are also updates to NUMPY。
I am Beeware environment making APP
But added the airtest module**

Or where do I need to change, I hope the seniors can give me direction